# Servidor apache parou de gravar acessos no arquivo access.log

Tags: apache, log

Estou executando um experimento de ataques DDoS a um servidor apache virtual (VMWare).O ataque foi ao serviço apache e não à máquina.

A partir de certo horário (10h20), embora houvesse máquinas fazendo requisições ao Apache, o arquivo access.log não registrou mais.O último registro do log foi de erro 408 (por causa do ataque).

O serviço do apache não parou (eu verifiquei). Alguma ideia do que houve?
O servidor virtual executava Debian em modo texto.

Veja que o log parou entre 10h20-11h20
[image: Logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sempre se lembre de checar os [códigos http em gatos](https://http.cat):

[image: Adeus, vida cruel #morri]

Basicamente, você fez tanta execução ao apache que algumas partes dele disseram "adeus, vida cruel". Uma dessas partes foi o logger/appender, que não suportou ao excesso de requisições; O apache ficou tão lotado que não conseguia nem responder em tempo hábil uma requisição, imagina enfileirar o resultado de todas essas repetições.

Eu andei procurando aqui como o apache lida com as requisições. Eu pensei que para cada requisição ele abria uma nova thread, porém não encontrei numa busca rápida algo confirmando minhas suspeitas... Entretanto, achei uma referência em inglês sobre [o ciclo de vida de uma requisição HTTP no apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/dev/request). Talvez valha a pena dar uma lida.

## EDIT

Achei alguma referência sobre apache e threads numa [questção no StackOverflow internacional](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19324442/4438007). Basicamente, cada requisição que o apache consegue atender, ele criará um novo contexto de programa para atendê-la. Isso pode gerar um gargalo de processamento (cada núcleo de processamento só pode atender a um único *contexto* nesse sentido) como também um gargalo na memória (cada contexto exige um tanto de memória para rodar; se nós fingíssemos que precisa de 1KB para rodar, então 1 milhão de requisição irá criar 1 milhão de contextos diferentes, portanto, nesse cenário, ele precisaria de no mínimo 1GB somente de informação inicial de contexto; **ÊNFASE: ESSE É UM EXEMPLO COM DADOS INVENTADOS SEM BASE NA REALIDADE, USADO APENAS PARA EXPLICAR O PESO DESSAS MUITAS THREADS**).

Para evitar esse tipo de vulnerabilidade, o [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) (um servidor puramente `JavaScript`) usa um número limitado de threads para atender as requisições, normalmente apenas uma.

Concluindo, seria bom ter um gráfico analisando a performance do servidor mostrando o quanto de CPU e de memória está sendo usado.

Comment: eu postei o log.

Comment: Achei alguma referência sobre uma thread por request, então vou atualizar um pouco mais a minha respota. Talvez essa parada de não atender requisições de 10h20-11h20 seja uma estratégia de autopreservação do servidor, preciso verificar isso.

Comment: O que eu devo observar no historico do servidor? uso de memoria? CPU? já que log nao registrou?

Comment: Sim, sugiro exatamente isso. Achei um [artigo em inglês](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E408.html) falando sore a dificuldade de resolver esse problema. Outra possibilidade para resolver o problema é usar uma estratégia meio `node.js`, onde há um número limitado de threads disponíveis para responder as requisições, porém não lembro se é possível configurar isso no apache (creio que seja).

Comment: Acabei de encontrar a comunidade [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), da família do _Stack Exchange_. Encontrei uma pergunta sobre [erro 408](http://serverfault.com/questions/383290/too-many-408-error-codes-in-access-log). Talvez seja interessante cavar por lá um pouco mais